# Appearance cube sandy

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, sandy3d

I'm a newbie with sandy and action script 3. I have followed a tutorial on the sandy web site and I created a cube.

But I wasn't successful in creating a cube with a different textures on each cube face. My first texture is duplicated on each face.

So, how can I have a different texture on each face? I haven't found how to do that on the sandy web site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys, here is the code:

```
var materialFace1:BitmapMaterial = new BitmapMaterial( bitmap1.bitmapData );
materialFace1.lightingEnable = true;
var appFace1:Appearance = new Appearance( materialFace1 );

var materialFace2:BitmapMaterial = new BitmapMaterial( bitmap2.bitmapData );
materialFace2.lightingEnable = true;
var appFace2:Appearance = new Appearance( materialFace2 );

var materialFace3:BitmapMaterial = new BitmapMaterial( bitmap3.bitmapData );
materialFace3.lightingEnable = true;
var appFace3:Appearance = new Appearance( materialFace3 );

var materialFace4:BitmapMaterial = new BitmapMaterial( bitmap4.bitmapData );
materialFace4.lightingEnable = true;
var appFace4:Appearance = new Appearance( materialFace4 );

var materialFace5:BitmapMaterial = new BitmapMaterial( bitmap5.bitmapData );
materialFace5.lightingEnable = true;
var appFace5:Appearance = new Appearance( materialFace5 );

var materialFace6:BitmapMaterial = new BitmapMaterial( bitmap6.bitmapData );
materialFace6.lightingEnable = true;
var appFace6:Appearance = new Appearance( materialFace6 );



var box:Box = new Box( "box",100,100,100);


    var face:PrimitiveFace = box.getFace(Box.FACE_LEFT);
    face.appearance = appFace1;

    face = box.getFace(Box.FACE_BOTTOM);
    face.appearance = appFace2;

    face = box.getFace(Box.FACE_FRONT);
    face.appearance = appFace3;

    face = box.getFace(Box.FACE_BACK);
    face.appearance = appFace4;

    face = box.getFace(Box.FACE_RIGHT);
    face.appearance = appFace5;

    face = box.getFace(Box.FACE_TOP);
    face.appearance = appFace6;
```

This code allows to have a cube with a different texture by face.